# jQuery $.ajax memory leak?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, memory-leaks

Why does jQuery ajax cause a horrible memory leak on Firefox & other browsers?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqfz7/

If you run this in a browser like Firefox, this causes the memory to climb. Has anyone else seen this? Is there a way to stop the memory leak with jQuery ajax? Thanks

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: "M"
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        setInterval(function() {
            get_some_stuff();
        }, 1000);
        load_count = load_count + 1;
        $('body h1').text('load_count: ' + load_count);             
    }
})
```

Comment: Is this code within `get_some_stuff`?

Comment: it's all the the jsfiddle url

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You want this to run 1000 times right. Is there a reason why you would two ajax requests out there at the same time? Wouldn't you want to wait for your response, before making your next call? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do SetTimeout instead of SetInterval.

Try this..

http://jsfiddle.net/Rqfz7/2/

Answer (score 4):

It is because you are calling `setInterval()` from within `get_some_stuff()` function. `setInterval` is used to run funciton over and over again at a specified time interval. Your issue is because all those registered functions calls (via `setInterval`) are executing every second and there are lots of them.

Comment: Right but after 1000 runs it will stop, that's why there is a counter.

Comment: @AnApprentice I think that you got the idea of how the method `setInterval` wrong, this is the syntax: `setInterval(code,millisec,lang)`, so that would be millisec of waiting time between the loop, not the number of times it will be executed

Comment: Yes but those functions are keep executing, because of `setInterval`, which executes all those funcitons every sencond.

Comment: @des, Yes -- sorry, I was responding to the pre-edit version of your answer, and then edited my comment in response to your edit. Looking over your answer again, I see you've completely corrected my initial complaint.

Comment: @des + 1 SetInterval() is most likely the real issue here; howerver, you should probably remove your initial statement as get_some_stuff() is meant to call itself.

Comment: @apsillers yeah, i should've put more emphasis on `setInterval` in first place, but thanks anyways.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You want this to run 1000 times right. Is there a reason why you would two ajax requests out there at the same time? Wouldn't you want to wait for your response, before making your next call? Or am i missing something?

Comment: @ek_ny it looks like you should put your comment under question

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling `get_some_stuff()` upon success of the ajax request. Additionally, every time the ajax request completes, you are setting a loop that calls the function after 1 second. Every time the ajax gets called you call another loop. If this went on for 1000 cycles, you'd have 1000 loops all calling the `get_some_stuff()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue, repeated ajax calls to a json web service resulted in heavy memory leaks even without any processing of the json object itself.

Turns out that there's a bug in jQuery I guess. Change your dataType to 'text', and then parse the resulting response with a library that doesn't use eval() which is what's causing the leaks I believe.

I found this library here [json_parse.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). So far it's working well, although it uses a bit more CPU.